# Ansible with multiline variables in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible, devops

This might seems weird, But I'm trying to create 2 shell scripts, one with variables which I can source, and another, with a function to run.

**core.vars**

```
#/bin/bash
# list of playbooks to source

# Core db initialization playbooks

core_db_init_play_books=$(cat <<EOL
../ansible/test.yaml -e "val1=hi val2=by"
../ansible/provision.yml --skip-tags "postgresql-slave,log-es"
../ansible/postgresql-data-update.yml
../ansible/es-mapping.yml --extra-vars "indices_name=all ansible_tag=run_all_index_and_mapping"
../ansible/cassandra-deploy.yml -e "cassandra_jar_path=$ansible_path/ansible cassandra_deploy_path=/home/{{ansible_ssh_user}}" -v
EOL
)
```

**install_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

## Ansible Runner
function ansible_runner() {
    playbooks=$1
    local IFS=$'\n' # seperate playbooks by newline
    for playbook in ${playbooks}; do
        ansible-playbook -i ../ansible/inventory/env ${playbook}
    done
}
source core.vars
ansible_runner core_db_init_play_books
```

But when you execute the install script, ansible will complain for files with extra-args

`playbook not found ../ansible/provision.yml --skip-tags "postgresql-slave,log-es"`

Think, it has something to do with the way I pass the file. Couldn't figure it out though.
Great minds please ... :)

Comment: The last line is missing a `$`. I think that this is a typo at SO, since you did have an error message with data from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

**install_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

## Ansible Runner
ansible_runner() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        declare -a playbook="($line)"   # split $line into tokens
        ansible-playbook -i ../ansible/inventory/env "${playbook[@]}"
    done <<< "$1"
}
source core.vars
ansible_runner "$core_db_init_play_books"
```

Now the option lines are properly split into an array of tokens with the `declare` statement.

Comment: thanks for your comment. But even that won't solve the problem. Now every words(considering space) is an entry(and quoted strings all one). But how will we pass the entire line to ansible?

Comment: @RajeshRajendran Thank you for the prompt feedback. Sorry for my incomplete answer. Now I hope
I've understood the requirements correctly. Would you please try my updated
answer? BR.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your update. A small hiccup though,`+ ansible-playbook -i ../ansible/inventory/env ../ansible/test.yaml -e '"val1=hi' 'val2=by"'`. Because of that, Now will get undefined variable.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I've updated `core.vars` by removing the surrounding quotes. Would you please try again?

Comment: thankyou for helping out. But the idea is to keep the syntax inline with ansible, so that anybody can append one more playbook with bunch of variables and it should work. So I think heavy customization will harm, more than good

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you for your time to test my codes anyway.

Comment: @RajeshRajendran Sorry for annoying you so often but now I've understood your concept and came up with a (hopefully) proper  solution. It does not require to change the file `core.vars`. Would you please try to test it? BR.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `IFS`. You need the spaces when you don't want `../ansible/provision.yml --skip-tags "postgresql-slave,log-es"` to be one long filename.
Processing the variable by line and having spaces becomes hard with a `for-loop`.
Try this:

```
function ansible_runner() {
    while IFS= read -r playbook; do
        echo ansible-playbook -i ../ansible/inventory/env ${playbook}
    done <<< "$1"
}
ansible_runner "${core_db_init_play_books}"
```